# Skip first line using Open CSV reader

Tags: java, opencsv

Here is the line i am using currently

```
File booleanTopicFile;
// booleanTopicFile is csv file uploaded from form
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(booleanTopicFile), "UTF-8"));
```

Want to skip the first line of the csv which contains headings.
I dont want to use any separator as except the default one comma(,) which is already available in default constructor.
In parameterized constructor there is a option to skip no. of lines but how to deal with the 2nd and 3rd param of the constructor.

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(Reader reader, char c, char c1, int index);
```

--
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just read the first line and do nothing with it?

Comment: csvReader.readNext(); before the loop, is an alternative solution, but would be optimal if its possible through constructor.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This constructor of CSVReader class will skip 1st line of the csv while reading the file.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), ',', '\'', 1);
```

Comment: +1 Correct answer but don't most CSV files use double quoting ? So it would be `new CSVReader(new StringReader(csvText), CSVReader.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVReader.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, 1);` instead.

Comment: In version 2.3 the *DEFAULT_SEPARATOR* and *DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER* are now in *CSVParser* class.

Comment: There is one issue with this. If a csv is having values containing single quote, it will skip that record. e.g Adrian,D'sousa,Agent

Comment: Just fyi, but this constructor is deprecated in Version 4.0. Not sure how I can achieve the same functionality without using deprecated methods.

Comment: this is deprecated you can use  => 


`CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader(csvFileName)).withSkipLines(1).build()`

Answer (score 28):

At least since version 3.8 you can use the `CSVReaderBuilder` and set it to skip the first line.

Example:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(inputStreamReader)
                .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.EMPTY_SEPARATORS)
                // Skip the header
                .withSkipLines(1)
                .build();
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it, forget the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

I found this question and response helpful, I'd like to expand on [Christophe Roussy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579670/skip-first-line-using-open-csv-reader#comment29232819_14642507). In the latest opencsv (2.3 as of this writing) The actual line of code is:

```
new CSVReader( new StringReader(csvText), CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
               CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, 1);
```

Note it uses CSVParser instead of CSVReader.

Comment: Very helpful. I was looking for a way to use a null char for the quote parameter, when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 5):

with latest version opencsv version use -

`CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("book.csv")).withSkipLines(1).build()`

Comment: That's what I said in my answer from 2016.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `withFilter`:

```
watFileCsvBeans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<ClassType>(isr)
  .withType(ClassType.class)
  .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
  // CsvToBeanFilter with a custom allowLine implementation
  .withFilter(line -> !line[0].equals("skipme"))
  .build()
  .parse();
```

Comment: withSkipLine() worked perfectly, but withFilter() notworking.

Answer (score -1):

```
watFileCsvBeans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<ClassType>(isr)
  .withType(ClassType.class)
  .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
  // CsvToBeanFilter with a custom allowLine implementation
  .withFilter(line -> !line[0].equals("skipme"))
  .build()
  .parse();
```

It's useful in my case. Instead, "withSkipLines" is not working for me.
opencsv version: 5.5.2